# Partial class template specialization not considered neither by GCC or CLang

Tags: c++, templates, partial-specialization

Given this simple example:

```cpp
template<class T, class TT>
class make_it { };

template<class T>
class make_it<T, T*> { };

make_it<int>
```

I would expect to be able to use it both as `make_it<type, type>` and `make_it<type>` but the example template invocation at the end of the code does not compile.

When trying to compile it with GCCI get:

> test-partial-spec.cpp:8:12: error: wrong number of template arguments (1, should be 2)

Same with CLang:

> test-partial-spec.cpp:8:1: error: too few template arguments for class template 'make_it'

What puzzles me more is that when I take the example from [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/partial_specialization):

```cpp
template<class T1, class T2, int I>
class A {};

template<class T, int I>
class A<T, T*, I> {};

A<int, 3>
```

It does not compile as well:
GCC:

```
test-partial-spec.cpp:18:9: error: wrong number of template arguments (2, should be 3)
   18 | A<int, 3>
      |         ^
```

CLang:

```
test-partial-spec.cpp:18:8: error: template argument for template type parameter must be a type
A<int, 3>
       ^
```

This might look like an easy question, but how do I define a partial specialization with less parameters than the generic template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't make a partial specialization which takes fewer parameters than the primary template: they have to take the same amount.

Your partial specialization lets you customize the behaviour of `make_if` for the case where the second template argument is a pointer to the first.

If you instead want to *default* the second parameter to be a pointer to the first template argument, such that `make_it<int>` is the same as `make_it<int, int*>` you can do this:

```
template<class T, class TT = T*>
class make_it { };
```

Or to make it work in some corner cases, like when `T` is a reference:

```
template<class T, class TT = std::add_pointer_t<T>>
class make_it { };
```

Comment: My example is just an absolutely minimal piece of code that demonstrates the problem. It's not what I really need in my code. So no, I don't want "T*" as second parameter, it's there just to show one of possible cases.

What I really need is to be able to make multiple partial specializations, like
```template<class T> class make_it<T,int> { ... some code for TT=int ... }```, 
```template<class T> class make_it<T,float> { ... different code for TT=float ... }```
And, well, according to cppreference site I gave a link to in my question, partial references can have any number of arguments.

Comment: @AndreyZabolotnyi if the user writes `make_it<double>` then which of those should be selected?

Comment: Partial specializations allow you to customize a given primary template for specific arguments. So that `make_it<T,int>` specialization will be selected for `make_it<int,int>` and `make_it<std::string,int>` and `make_it<chicken,int>`, whatever, as long as the second argument is `int`. The template still requires two arguments.

Comment: Thank you for clarification! I was thinking about it the other way around. The arguments to partial speciailzation are not the ones in angle brackets after template<>, but the arguments to the generic template (and to the specialized class<>).
So, my specialized make_it will be instantiated when I invoke make_it<some type, int> and when I invoke make_it<some type, not int> it will invoke the generic template.
Thank you once again.